# What do I connect this white wire to for my light fixture install?

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I’m trying to install a light fixture in my living room. However, I see the white wire is disconneted from the ceiling. Where does the white wire supposed to be connected?

(The disconnected white wire is “white”, the connected white wire is “black”)

[image]

Comment: That's a great picture (congrats on providing one, so many don't think to do so!), however, it would be even better if you were to [edit] in a picture showing the other end of that stranded white wire, and one showing the inside of the box giving us a clue what other wires are available to you. For example, the white on the left seems to go into a wire nut - what's that attached to? Pull all the wires out of the box (_without_ disconnecting any of them) so we can clearly see what you can see.

Comment: Where the previous fixture's white was connected, if the previous fixture worked...

Comment: Most of the time there should be a white wire in the box.  The picture does not show one yet.

Answer (score 2):

[image: detail with exposure adjusted]

So, adjusting the picture in hopes of seeing more, we see the "fixture black/hot that is white" connects to red (suffering some white paint.) Given it's a typical USA-style box, red implies cable with black, red, and white wires, plus a ground wire if not ancient.

We'll assume that's in the right place, for the moment.

Therefore the blacks that are presently twisted together but bare are **most likely** the "always hot" (and should have a wire nut in place on them) and the red is **most likely** "switched hot," which means there should be a set of white (or at least they started life white, they don't always age well and may look beige, tan, etc.) wires that should be Neutral, and which your fixture's white neutral should connect to.